# Telerik Kendo MVC Grid Validation Always Fails

Tags: validation, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am tearing my hair out with this...!

I have a telerik kendo mvc ui grid widget using an Inline gridedit mode. When the user adds a new entry to the grid (by way of a custom dropdown edit control), I want it to validate that this entry is not already present in the grid.

I have an MVC controller action that does this and returns True or False accordingly. This works perfectly. Here is the validator javascript code I am using.

```
    (function ($, kendo) {
    $.extend(true, kendo.ui.validator, {
        rules: {
            bedQuantity: function (input, params) {
                if (input.is("[name='Quantity']") && input.val() <= 0) {
                    input.attr("data-bedQuantity-msg", "Quantity must be 1 or more");
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            },
            bedExists: function(input, params) {
                if (input.is("[name='BedType']")) {
                    var model = {
                        PropertyId: @Model.Id,
                        BedTypeId: input.val()
                    };

                    var url = "/Property/ValidateBedTypeExists";
                    input.attr("data-val-bedExists-requested", true);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: url,
                        traditional: true,
                        data: JSON.stringify(model),
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        success: function(data) {
                            return data === false;
                        },
                        fail: function(data) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        },
        messages: {
            bedQuantity: function (input) {
                return input.attr("data-val-bedQuantity");
            },
            bedExists: function(input) {
                return "This bed type already exists";
            }
        }
    });
})(jQuery, kendo);
```

No matter whether the ajax call returns true or false, the validator always flags the entry as invalid.

Comment: I'd guess that the validator finishes before the ajax reques doest. Either you mark your request as `async: false` (see https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) or you submit the data to the controller and let it validate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the html attribute for the kendoDropdownList as required like this

```js
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
    .DataValueField("")
                    .DataTextField("")

                        .Name("")
                       
                        .HtmlAttributes(new { required ="required" })
.OptionLabel("- Select a type - ")
.Filter(FilterType.Contains)

               

     )
```

Try this..